# Linq: get parents based on value of child property

Tags: c#, linq

I have parents with multiple children that have a property to check.
I need to get the parents where the child has X property with N value.

Markets have
UserAlerts have
one User

I want all the markets that have UserAlerts with the User Property to be the current user.

```
var markets = _context.Markets.Include("UserAlerts").AsEnumerable();

markets = from m in markets
          where markets.Any(x => x.UserAlerts == _context.UserAlerts.Where(o => o.User == theUser))
          select m;
```

this doesn't work. Any ideas?

I can't get .Contains or .Intersect to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your data model correctly, the following query will return all `Market` with at least one of its `UserAlert` child has `User` equals current user :

```
markets = from m in markets
          where m.UserAlerts.Any(ua => ua.User == theUser)
          select m;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following

```
var markets = markers.where(m=>m.UserAlerts.Any(alert => alert.User == theUser).select(m);
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile